# htaccess Redirect URL with GET Parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL that is in the format `http://www.example.com/?s=query`

I want to redirect this URL to `http://www.example.com/search/query`

I have the following `.htaccess` but I wanted to check if there is anything wrong with this. My `RewriteRule` looks a little wonky and I don't know if it will cause problems for other URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1? [NC,L,R]
```

I ran a test [Here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=77257bce-a9bb-479c-ade1-5157648a6f11) and it seems to redirect to the correct URL.

Comment: Looks ok-ish to me. But you will also need to take care to actually handle incoming requests using that new form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1? [NC,L,R]
> ```

You will likely need the `NE` (`noescape`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive if you are receiving a %-encoded URL parameter value, otherwise the target URL will be doubly-encoded. The `QUERY_STRING` server variable is not decoded by Apache.

It also depends on how you are rewriting `/search/query` back to `/?s=query` (or presumably more like `/index.php?s=query`?) - presumably you are already doing this later in the config? You only want this redirect to apply to direct requests and not rewritten requests (otherwise you'll get a redirect loop). An easy way to ensure this is to check that the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is empty.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1 [NE,QSD,R,L]
```

Other points:

- The `QSD` flag would be preferable (on Apache 2.4) to appending `?` to the end of the *susbtitution* string in order to remove the query string.
- The regex `^s=(.*)` (the trailing `$` was superfluous) does assume that `s` is the only URL parameter at the start of the query string. As it stands, *everything* is assumed to be part of this value. eg. `s=foo&bar=1` will result in `/search/foo&bar=1`.
- The `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive is superfluous.
- Should you also be checking for `/index.php?s=<query>`? (Or whatever file/DirectoryIndex is handling the request.)